# Large ASP.NET MVC Application Considerations

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've done a large study into using MVC and thanks to the people here a lot of the issues revolving around it have been cleared up for me.

The problems I'm having now revolve around the sheer size of our application and how it would be organised within the project itself.  For example, we have url's such as http://mylocalapp/folder/nestedfolder/subfolder/theapp.  The reason we do this is because the application quite literally is that large.  We *need* that kind of folder structure because otherwise the application would be unmanageable.

Phil Haack [covers the registering of routes for nested folders in one of his blog posts](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx) which is very useful indeed, but our application has sub-applications and sub-applications within that.  It couldn't be simplified any further.

What steps need to be taken to manage such a large application which spans a large amount of folders and has folders up to seven levels deep, as well as having about 15 databases?  Is MVC really the answer for an application of this size?

Is another option simply to apply lots of URL routing and map route areas for all the separate sub-folders?

Comment: What do you mean by subapplications?  Are they setup as application in IIS or are they just in a sub folder, but have a unique/individualized "application" experience?  just curious.

Comment: Yes, more like areas.  I'd call them sub-applications because they 'do' different things but are actually a part of the application on a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per a comment "Are you refering to "Areas"?" was the answer eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to have everything inside of one application, why not create an MVC application in each folder?

Comment: That's one idea.  Is it also possible to set up loads of routes pointing to each directory?

Comment: I haven't done much routing, so I wouldn't know. My initial thought was, if it is really this complex, it probably deserves to be parted into smaller and simpler applications.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation and what we did was instead of making a "fat" controller, we make them "skinny". Ian Cooper has an excellent write-up [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/12/03/the-fat-controller.aspx).

So what we did is we broke down the "sub-applications" to be its own application. I think this is what the previous posters trying to convey as well.